# Evaluating which point of the square a point is closer to

Tags: geometry

Given a $1 \times 1$ square ABCD, suppose there is a point $P$ inside it.

Picking one diagonal of choice ($AD$ or $BC$), what is the most optimized way of finding out which point is closer to $P$?

[image]

For example, I could pick $BC$. In order to know if $P$ is closer to $B$ or to $C$, I could simply compare $||P-B||$ and $||P-C||$, but that would require a bunch of operations including some powers and some square roots (which for the sake of optimization, can be removed). I would like to know if there is a better way or evaluating this.

Comment: The way your question is phrased is a bit confusing to me, but let's take $AD$ as in your diagram. If you want to figure out whether $P$ is closer to $B$ or closer to $C$, can't you just do two inequality tests on its coordinates to check whether it's in the triangle $ACD$ or in the triangle $ACB$?

Comment: @AlkaKadri sure can. How should these inequalities be?

Comment: Let's take the origin $O = (0,0)$. Then the line $AD$ can be plotted as $y = -x$. So with $P = (a,b)$, the point $P$ is in the lower triangle if and only if $b < -a$ (so actually it's just one inequality test). If $b = -a$ then it's on the line $AD$, and so it's equidistant to both points $C$ and $B$.

Comment: You just need to drop a perpendicular from $P$ onto your diagonal of choice.  The foot of this perpendicular is the closest point on the diagonal to your point $P$.

Comment: @AlkaKadri neat! Good catch!